# ActionMailer User object injection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionmailer, ruby-on-rails-4.1, ruby-2.1

This is frustrating me. For some reason, whenever we are sending an email, ActionMailer insists on checking the User model for a user with that email address.

We have the method defined like this:

```
class MonitorMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default :from => "validemail@ourplace.org"
  def email_importer_errors_found
    mail(to: "validto@ourplace.org", subject: "Errors found in import error folder ")
  end
end
```

When we call the method, we are getting the following (note Query Trace is from the Active Record Query Trace gem (https://github.com/ruckus/active-record-query-trace):

```
Rendered monitor_mailer/email_importer_errors_found.html.erb (0.2ms)
User Load (2.4ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users`  WHERE `users`.`email` = 'validto@ourplace.org'  ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
Query Trace > app/mailers/monitor_mailer.rb:28:in `email_importer_errors_found'
Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'users.email' in 'where clause': SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users`  WHERE `users`.`email` = 'validto@ourplace.org'  ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1

MonitorMailer#email_importer_errors_found: processed outbound mail in 167.3ms
 => #<Mail::Message:108716380, Multipart: false, Headers: <Date: Wed, 06 Apr 2016 13:56:55 -0400>, ...
```

Why is the ActionMailer trying to look up the User in the Users table? We are using LDAP auth via Devise and our gemfile is:
    source 'http://rubygems.org'

```
gem 'rails', '4.1.15'
gem "mysql2", '0.3.15'
gem 'protected_attributes', '~> 1.0.8'

gem 'devise', '~> 3.4.1'
gem 'net-ldap', '~> 0.3.1'
gem 'devise_ldap_authenticatable', '0.8.4'

gem 'ruby-oci8', '~> 2.2.1'
gem 'nokogiri', '~> 1.6', '>= 1.6.7.1'
gem "net-sftp"
gem 'sshkit', '1.8.1'

gem 'prawn'
gem "prawnto_2", :require => "prawnto"
gem 'prawn-labels'
gem 'prawn-table'

gem 'whenever', "0.9.4", :require => false
gem 'delayed_job', '4.0.1'
gem 'delayed_job_active_record', '4.0.1'

gem 'mailboxer', "~> 0.13.0"
gem 'mailkick', '~> 0.1.3'

gem "daemons", '~> 1.1.9'

gem 'hairtrigger', '0.2.17'

group :development do
  gem 'capistrano', '~> 3.1.0'
  gem 'capistrano-bundler', '~> 1.1.2'
  gem 'capistrano-rvm', '~> 0.1.2'
  gem 'capistrano-rails', '~> 1.1'
  gem 'capistrano3-delayed-job', '~> 1.0'
  gem 'brakeman'
  gem 'quiet_assets'
  gem 'rack-insight'
  gem 'active_record_query_trace'
end

group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.14.0'
end

gem 'paper_trail', '~> 3.0.2'
gem 'settingslogic'

gem 'cancancan', '1.12.0'

gem 'attr_encrypted', '1.3.5'

gem 'jquery-rails', '~> 3.1.0'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'

gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
```

What am I missing here that is causing it to fire that query? I am thinking Devise is trying to be smart here, but I can't figure out where it is injecting itself.

Comment: Can you get query_trace to output a full stacktrace somehow?

Comment: Please add the content of `monitor_mailer/email_importer_errors_found.html.erb` to your question and any email layouts and any partials rendered. (trim the static text if you like, interested in the ERB <% %> stuff)

Comment: After looking at the stacktrace a little deeper (as suggested by shelvacu), it looks like it is an error with the way the Mailkick gem is working.

I have entered an issue on github for it (https://github.com/ankane/mailkick/issues/19) and working with the developer to fix it.